# Center a minus on the screen in java

Tags: java, center

I am trying to center a minus sign on the screen using the following code:

```
text = "-";
textPosition = new Point();
Rect bounds = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
textPosition.x = (int) (myArea.left + myArea.width() / 2);
textPosition.y = (int) (myArea.top + myArea.height() / 2 + bounds.height() / 2);
canvas.drawText(text, textPosition.x, textPosition.y, paint);
```

This code works like a charm when "text" is something else (for example a plus sign), but in this case the minus sign is positioned too high on the screen.

EDIT: 
Here is the result for four different operators.

[image: Operators, each centered in their own screen area]

And... the funny thing is, that I created my own font to display these operators. So I know, that it should be centered correctly.

PS: Now that I look at it, all off them seem a little off, though the minus-sign is the worst...

Comment: Would you provide us the current screen and the expected one?

Comment: I am not sure if screen sharing helps. The thing is, that the minus is not centered vertically. By the way, in the case of "_" it gets centered correctly. What I want is a nice little box with a "-" in the center of it.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis: I have updated the description and included a screenshot. Hope (or someone else) you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it. Not by changing the code, but by changing the font. I have now aligned all characters on the baseline and that seems to work.